# How do I use in clause while using case when statement in where clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

How do I use in clause in the else block of a case when statement, in the where clause, for eg:

```
    select * 
    from dummy_table dt 
    where dt.some_column_1 in 
    (case when 
          dt.some_column_2 in (9,10) then dt.some_column_3
          else (dt.some_column_4,dt.some_column_5)
    end);
```

Comment: Can anyone please answer this?, or give an alternate way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to modify above alternative little

```
SELECT *
  FROM dummy_table dt
 WHERE ( dt.some_column_2 IN ( 9, 10 )
         AND dt.some_column_1 = dt.some_column_3 )
    OR ( dt.some_column_2 NOTIN ( 9, 10 ) AND dt.some_column_1 IN ( dt.some_column_4, dt.some_column_5 );
```

Comment: Thanks Vidya I am doing this, I guess it work. Thanks for ur response ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The IN clause can only take (a) an [expression list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions014.htm#i1033664) or (b) a select statement returning a set of rows. Your query is giving it a CASE statement inside parentheses.

I can think of a few ways to do this; there are a lot more.

```
select *
from dummy_table dt
where dt.some_column_1 in 
(select dt.some_column_3 from dual where dt.some_column_2 in (9,10)
union select dt.some_column_4 from dual where dt.some_column_2 not in (9,10)
union select dt.some_column_5 from dual where dt.some_column_2 not in (9,10));

select *
from dummy_table dt
where dt.some_column_1 in 
(case when dt.some_column_2 in (9,10) then dt.some_column_3 else null end,
 case when dt.some_column_2 not in (9,10) then dt.some_column_4 else null end,
 case when dt.some_column_2 not in (9,10) then dt.some_column_5 else null end)
;

select *
from dummy_table dt
where (dt.some_column_2 in (9,10) and dt.some_column_1 = dt.some_column_3)
   or (dt.some_column_2 not in (9,10) and dt.some_column_1 in (dt.some_column_4, dt.some_column_5))
;
```

Comment: Hi kfinity, I am currently trying what Kobi and Vidya have suggested, if that doesn't work I will definitely try ur suggestion. Thanks for ur response! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way can be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dummy_table dt
 WHERE ( dt.some_column_2 IN ( 9, 10 )
         AND dt.some_column_1 = dt.some_column_3 )
    OR ( dt.some_column_2 NOT IN ( 9, 10 )
         AND dt.some_column_1 IN ( dt.some_column_4, dt.some_column_5 ) );
```

**Update with NOT IN in the secord part**

Comment: Thanks Kobi for this, I think this will work. Thanks again! :)

Comment: If column_2 is 9 and column_1 in (column_4, column_5), this will return the row, which is not quite the same as the original query logic. The second half of OR needs `dt.some_column_2 NOT IN (9,10)` to be equivalent.

Comment: @MridulMadhukar, don't forget to mark as answer if it fits your needs and why not, have a look at other answers

Comment: Thanks Kobi I am trying this along with the other suggestions, once I get a correct output I will definitely mark the answer